# How do I set up Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS to serve as a samba Primary Domain Controller uses pam modules to authenticate against an LDAP server?

Tags: server, ldap, samba

I'd like to have a Samba server that appears as a Primary Domain Controller (PDC) to a bunch of windows lab computers. But instead of having the users have accounts with passwords stored on this Samba PDC, I'd like to have all the account information stored on our functioning LDAP server.

So, when a user logs into a Windows lab machine, they can do so with their LDAP username and password. If I have to change their password, I just have to do it in the LDAP server. The next time they log into this "proxy PDC," they'll be able to use their new LDAP password.

I have a functioning LDAP server and a server that I can use to create the Samba PDC. I've played around with Samba before, but I've always had to have a local Linux account for each user that I wanted to access samba and I had to create a corresponding Samba account for each of those users. Those are the steps that I'd like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are guides like [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=640760) which look at this issue thoroughly.

I find this quite difficult to answer, given all the variables. Since samba and openldap need some extra configuration, an answer here might not be complete.

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty easy howto [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/openldap-samba-domain-controller-ubuntu7.10) and although it was written for Ubuntu 7.10 it still works i just tested it.. Even though i didn't install webmin, i better like editing the DNS (bind9) config files by hand.

Comment: voted up, but can you state what version it "still works" on?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Ubuntu Server Guide](http://doc.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/serverguide/C/). It explains the integration of Samba and LDAP and many other topics. It's updated for every Ubuntu Version.